# Using a query to update existing records.

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

Basically, I have a table of data with plenty of records (10,000+)

They all have 4 fields in common which must have data entered. The unique data is TIME.

I have already done a group sort query which has identified the group's of data based on these 4 fields, and then calculated an average time for each group.

I'm now needing to re-insert the average time against the real time in a table so each individual record's time can be evaluated against the average of its type.

For instance, one group from the query would have the result

Process1, Week2, Operator3, Shift4, AvgOfTIME = 120.70

It would then need to re-insert that average time into all records that match those criteria, but do it for every group result and record.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

you need to update table use subquery

```
update t1 set t1.timefield = s2.AvgOfTIME
from yourtable t1
inner join 
(
  -- you query for calculating avg time
)
as t2
on t1.Process1 = t2.Process1 and t1.Week2 = t2.Week2 and t1.Operator3 = t2.Operator3 and       t1.Shift4 = t2.Shift4
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.

My problem is that the group by query returns around 7,000 different groups. 
Therefore I'm trying to get the update query to update all the records where they match the corresponding group. Else, I'd have to either create 7,000 update querys or do it manually?

Comment: I do not know about your table schema but guest that you need do to something like that
'
    update t1 set t1.timefield = s2.AvgOfTIME
    from yourtable t1
    inner join 
    (
    select Process1, Week2, Operator3, Shift4, Avg(timefield) as AvgOfTIME from yourtable 
    group by Process1, Week2, Operator3, Shift4, Avg(timefield)
    )
    as t2
    on t1.Process1 = t2.Process1 and t1.Week2 = t2.Week2 and t1.Operator3 = t2.Operator3 and  t1.Shift4 = t2.Shift4'